# What keyboard shortcut brings up the Powerpoint 2016 Format Shape/Object pane

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

Is there a reliable way of bringing up the format pane via the keyboard once I've selected an object that I want to format (e.g., a shape, or text box)? I've variously seen that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> does this but it doesn't appear to work in my version of Powerpoint (the Office365 Home Edition version). I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALT+HO  (that's OH, not ZERO)  Plus a few more characters so SO will let me post the answer.  ;-)

Comment: Instead of padding it with garbage, why not elaborate on it a little, or use keycap formatting?  Is that really an equal sign?